# load image with ajax until call completes

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using a small piece of ajax in two different projects that I would like to show a loading image prior to the call to the scripting completing. This is the code being used.

```
 if ($http) {
  $http.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (/4|^complete$/.test($http.readyState)) {
      document.getElementById('attributes').innerHTML = $http.responseText;
        setTimeout(function(){$self();}, 1500);
    }
 };

    $http.open('GET', 'attributes.php' + '?' + 'cat_id=<?php echo $hc_cat; ?>' + '&sub_cat=<?php echo $hc_sub_cat; ?>' + '&prod_id=<?php echo $pnumber; ?>', true);
    $http.send(null);
 }
```

I'm curious as to whether showing an image of loading can be implemented, and more importantly how I could go about doing so. Any input is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Just add `document.getElementById('attributes').innerHTML = "<img src='/imgs/ajax-loader.gif'>"` before the open/send call.

Answer (score 0):

Just add something like:

```
document.getElementById('attributes').innerHTML = "<img src='/imgs/ajax-loader.gif'>"
```

before the open/send call.